# Is it possible to deduce type conversion to templated type in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I want to create a class which is implicitly convertable to another class with template parameter. Here is MCE of what I want to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A {
    T value;
public:
    A(T value) {this->value = value;}
    T getValue() const {return value;}
};

class B {
    int value;
public:
    B(int value) {this->value = value;}
    operator A<int>() const {return A(value);}
};

template <typename T>
void F(A<T> a) {std::cout << a.getValue() << std::endl;}

void G(A<int> a)  {std::cout << a.getValue() << std::endl;}

int main()
{
    B b(42);

    F(b);           // Incorrect
    F((A<int>)b);   // Correct
    G(b);           // Also correct
}
```

Is it possible to make `F(b)` example work if both `class A` and `void F` are library functions and can't be modifyed?

Comment: Nope. Calling `F` like you do means template argument deduction. Which in turn means conversions are not considered. You may call `F<int>(b)` however.

Comment: Depending on the design and use-cases, maybe make `B` inherit from `A` instead? Possibly using `private` inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
F(b);
```

requires template argument *deduction*. As a result, it won't do what you want.

Try passing explicitly the argument template, like this:

```
F<int>(b);
```

since you provide a `()` operator in `class B`.